# What is the difference between PBYTE and BYTE*?

Tags: c++

Well as the windows datatypes say `PBYTE` is just a pointer to a `BYTE` so what is the difference in `c++` between declaring a `BYTE*` and `PBYTE` ? Also what is the difference between `PBYTE` AND `LPBYTE` ? is `L` stands for `LONG` ?

Comment: With window's visual studio definitions, there is no difference.  In general C++, BYTE and PBYTE aren't anything whatsoever.

Comment: @Aggieboy what do you mean by `aren't anything whatsoever` ?

Comment: - and the L prefix is there for historical reason, from back when there were multiple pointer sizes - thankfully we've moved on from that.

Comment: `BYTE k` won't compile on any arbitrary C++ compiler because it's not a real primitive.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError i think all pointers are 8 bytes of data right ?

Comment: Yes, on a 64-bit platform.

Comment: @DanielEugen Pointer size is machine's word size.

Comment: @DanielEugen: It depends on the architecture you're compiling for.  Some systems they're 8 bytes, on others 4, and on other still you have 2 byte pointers and 4 byte `far` pointers.

Comment: @Aggieboy: `BYTE` and `PBYTE` are perfectly valid identifiers, with whatever meaning is given to them by their declarations, if any. There are no such declarations in the standard C++ library, making them no more or less significant *as far as standard C++ is concerned* than `LDFF` and `RJMFZ` (I just generated those randomly). Certainly `BYTE k;` will compile if it's preceded by an appropriate definition for `BYTE` -- a definition that happens to be provided on Windows.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy: Pointer size is pointer size. A pointer may or may not be one "word" in size, whatever "word" means (there's no universal definition). Different types of pointers can even have different sizes, though that's not common. If you need to know how big a particular pointer is, use `sizeof`.

Comment: There is nothing reasonable in "windows.h" to justify the pollution done to the preprocessor, besides the the attempt(!) to cover all systems/platforms

Answer (score 7):

In naming conventions where PBYTE and BYTE are typedefs, PBYTE is a pointer to BYTE.   So there is no meaningful difference between PBYTE and BYTE * (unless you declare more than one variable at a time.

So

```
PBYTE x, y;
```

declares two pointers but

```
BYTE *x, y;
```

declares x as a pointer, and y as a BYTE (it would be necessary to use an addition asterisk to make y a pointer.).   This sort of thing is a common source of errors - albeit errors that are often quickly detected by a compiler when the variables are used as intended.

With implementations that support multiple pointer sizes (e.g. near, far, huge), LPBYTE sometimes means a far pointer.      This is meaningless in standard C++ (one memory model).  However, some older architectures (e.g. older IBM compatible PC) which had a segmented memory architecture, with different types memory provided by distinct types of chips, and different pointer types were needed to address them.   Modern operating systems that do virtualisation abstract this sort of thing away.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Windows data types page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it is simple `typedef BYTE *PBYTE,*LPBYTE;`

Also you may found useful this page: [windef.h](https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2003-06/msg00470/windef.h).

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between PBYTE and BYTE*. The LPBYTE is BYTE far*.
What's [far pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Far_pointer)

Comment: I don't think "far pointers" are meaningful on modern Windows systems.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "I think so". According to [Victor Polevoy's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28242011/827263), `PBYTE` and `LPBYTE` are defined identically. (Probably they were distinct in earlier versions.)